# Product of two continuous, non-negative and monotone non-decreasing function is itself..

Tags: calculus, functions

My question is simple: 
is the product of two continuous, non-negative and monotone non-decreasing function itself a continuous, non-negative and monotone non-decreasing function?

I believe the result holds for [sequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1122965/160535) but I don't know enough advanced math to know if this implies this results also holds for continuous functions.

Comment: Well, what would you need to check? It seems fairly straightforward to prove that if $x<y$ then $0\leq f(x)\leq f(y)$ and $0\leq g(x)\leq g(y)$ implies $0\leq f(x)g(x)\leq f(y)g(y)$.

Comment: Yes, indeed: sorry thank you sire!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The product of two continuous functions is continuous.  Do you need me to prove this?

Similarly, if two numbers $a, b$ are non-negative, then $ab$ is non-negative.  Then it should be clear that if two functions $f(x), g(x)$ are non-negative, then the product $(fg)(x) := f(x)g(x)$ is non-negative.

Finally, if two functions are both monotone non-decreasing, then if $x \leq y$, we have: $0 \leq f(x) \leq f(y)$ and $0 \leq g(x) \leq g(y)$, and multiplying the first inequality by $g(x)$, we get $$0 \leq f(x)g(x) \leq f(y)g(x)$$ but since $g(x) \leq g(y)$, then $f(y)g(x) \leq f(y)g(y)$, so we have $$0 \leq f(x)g(x) \leq f(y)g(y)$$ and this shows the product is monotone non-decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

I am unaware of any detailed proof, but I know that the product of two continuous functions result in a continuous function, and since both the functions are non-negative at all points, their product will also be non-negative, at all points.

Comment: I understand, but it is the *non decreasing* part I worry about..